# HoldForm does not prevent evaluation

Tags: evaluation, hold

I'm still relatively new here, and I'm not a native speaker. I hope, I don't make any obvious mistakes when asking this question. For instance, I simply had no idea how to title it accurately. I'm sorry. I'm open to suggestions.

**I'd like to make the following list:**
2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>3</sup> ...

I'd like to print it out on paper, eventually.

**I have tried a lot, for instance:**
`Table[HoldForm[2]^n, {n, 0, 10}]` or `HoldForm[2]^# &[Table[n, {n, 0, 10}]]`

which both give me: { 1, 2, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>3</sup> } ...

Now, that's a good start, but it's not exactly what I need. I need the first two expressions unevaluated, too (2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>).

Do you have any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: In addition, maybe `Array[HoldForm[2^#]&, 11,0]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this

```
Table[HoldForm[2^n]/.n->i,{i,0,4}]
```

gives you your result in the form you wish

Answer (score 7):

A few additional alternatives:

```
2^HoldForm /@ Range[0, 4]
```

[image]

```
Table[With[{i = i}, HoldForm[2^i]], {i, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Pure function work.

```
HoldForm[2^#] & /@ Range[0, 10]
```